# org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceCreationException: Unable to parse the documen.

Tags: java, mongodb, pentaho

I am trying to generate reports using pentaho in java with mongodb.

my code is

```
try {
 ClassLoader classloader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
 URL reportDefinitionURL =
 classloader.getResource("reports/TestSalesOrderReportOuputValues.prpt");
 ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
 resourceManager.registerDefaults();
 Resource directly = resourceManager.createDirectly(
 reportDefinitionURL, MasterReport.class);
 return (MasterReport) directly.getResource();
 } catch (ResourceException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

getting exception like,

```
org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceCreationException: Unable to parse the document: ResourceKey{schema=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.bundleloader.ZipResourceBundleLoader, identifier=content.xml, factoryParameters={org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.FactoryParameterKey{name=repository}=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.repository.zipreader.ZipReadRepository@854e63b, org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.FactoryParameterKey{name=repository-loader}=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.bundleloader.ZipResourceBundleLoader@638a3572}, parent=ResourceKey{schema=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceLoader, identifier=file:/D:/java_works/nirvahak-wrokspace/samples/sample-erp/target/classes/reports/manogoTestVenu.prpt, factoryParameters={}, parent=null}}
```

please can any one help me.

Comment: Could you check the exception's cause and parent fields? There are many possible causes for this exception and usually there is where the answer is.

Comment: Venu Annaram were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This exception may be  thrown when classic engine is not started properly. Boot the classic engine first.

> ClassicEngineBoot.getInstance().start();

Comment: how exactly do we do this? I restarted my server once would that help?